# How to create Catalog attribute in Magento 2 Using Upgrade Script

Tags: magento2, attributes

I created attribute in Magento 2 using install script.
By this code.

```
namespace Custom\Features\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
   private $eavSetupFactory;
   private $attributeSetFactory;
   private $attributeSet;
   private $categorySetupFactory;

   public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory, CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory )
       {
           $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
           $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
           $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
       }

   public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
   {    // TO CREATE PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE
       if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.6') < 0) {
       $setup->startSetup();
       $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
           $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                   \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
               'feature_1',
               [
                    'group' => 'Autosettings',
                    'type'  => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Feature 1',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'required' => false,
                    'global' => 1,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'default' => null,
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => true,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => '',
                    'note' => 'Feature 1'
           ]
       );  

       $setup->endSetup();
   }
   }
}
```

Now I want create some attribute in catalog using Upgrade.

How to process same with another attribute in catalog using upgrade script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You need to increase version of your file under etc/module.xml.Suppose your version is 1.0.0 then increased it by 1.0.1

Now create UpgradeData.php under Setup folder.

```
    <?php 
    namespace WilliamsCommerce\OrderBy\Setup;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

    class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
    {
       private $eavSetupFactory;
       private $attributeSetFactory;
       private $attributeSet;
       private $categorySetupFactory;

       public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory, CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory )
           {
               $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
               $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
               $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
           }

       public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
       {    // TO CREATE PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE
           if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
           $setup->startSetup();
           $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
               $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                       \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                   'feature_1',
                   [
                        'group' => 'Product Details',
                        'type'  => 'varchar',
                        'label' => 'Feature 1',
                        'input' => 'text',
                        'frontend' => '',
                        'required' => false,
                        'global' => 1,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'required' => false,
                        'user_defined' => true,
                        'default' => null,
                        'searchable' => false,
                        'filterable' => false,
                        'comparable' => false,
                        'visible_on_front' => true,
                        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                        'unique' => false,
                        'apply_to' => '',
                        'note' => 'Feature 1'
               ]
           );  

           $setup->endSetup();
       }
       }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Eav attribute not custom table..

Comment: OK i am updating my code i have just created using upgrade data.

Comment: If it is use full to you then accept also it will help to others to find relevant answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same think you need to create an upgradData

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html

Tell me if you need more help, i can post you a code if you need