# add new column to catalog product entity table

Tags: magento2, database, product-attribute, catalog

I add new column to `catalog_product_entity`. so when i want to add new filter to collection i get this error
`The "user_id" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.`

```
$subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('user_id', array('eq' => '2'))
```

Comment: There may be two issues casuing this problem: You didn't add the column as eav attribute with backend_type = static (missing entry in `eav_attribute` table for attribute `user_id`) or the old DDL whithout your new column is cached (in this case try to flush the ddl cache: `bin/magento cache:flush db_ddl`)

Comment: @HelgeB how i can add column as static attribute ? can you give me more detail . for secund issue i clear cache and update and compile

Answer (score 1):

If you have added the column `user_id` manually to the table `catalog_product_entity` you can use the following way to filter your product collection:

```
$subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->where('user_id = 2');
```

or

```
$subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->where('e.user_id = 2'); 
//e is the reference for the table catalog_product_entity in the default product collection
```

That should work, beacuse this creates the SQL statement whithout checking if an attribute exists like the method `addFieldToFilter` does.

But it's not a good practice to alter core entity tables and add columns that way.

I would rather suggest to create a product attribute `user_id` of type integer and then your code with `addFieldToFilter` should work, without adding a column to `catalog_product_entity`.
If you really want / need the column in `catalog_product_entity` for whatever reason you should at least create a product attribute `user_id` of type static and then you can use your code with `addFieldToFilter` too.

An example how to create product attributes programmatically can be found here
[How to create Catalog attribute in Magento 2 Using Upgrade Script](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238530/how-to-create-catalog-attribute-in-magento-2-using-upgrade-script)

You have to set the correct type for your attribute (`'type'  => 'int'` for an integer attribute or `'type'  => 'static'` if you want to use your added column)

There are also a lot of other examples for attribute creation if you google for it.